# UV unwrap from Blender to Substance Painter

Tags: texturing, uv

I have unwrapped an object, of a sphere, and the unwrapping looks clean. I applied a colour grid to see how it lays out across the mesh, which looks correct. But when I apply a texture from Substance painter, that particular section looks stretched. Is this a Substance Painter issue, or the UV unwrap is wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That UV map looks like a map of the default cube that was used to model your object. Are you sure that you've actually unwrapped the object since you modelled it?

Comment: Your UV from the first image do have some stretching. You can notice that in the 4, the H and the lines above the H. Make sure that your unwrap is using the subdivision modifier

Comment: This is the method I have done. 

https://ibb.co/jvBrgdH

Ill provide the file as well.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=60xgSvPq" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/60xgSvPq/)